# How to install CWM Recovery in non-supported device, like Karbonn Titanium S5 Plus?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I have Karbonn Titanium S5 Plus. I want to install CWM Recovery, but my phone model is not supported.

How to install CWM Recovery in it? Also, can I install it without using a PC?

Answer (score 0):

Because CWM does not support your phone model, I assume you should search for an alternative  recovery (TWRP, Philz).
Most installing methods require something like `fastboot` or simply flashing an image to your phone, which is hard without a PC (Mobile ODIN may do the job, but I don't know about supported phone's).

For custom ROMs search [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) for your phone and that particular model in the appropriate subforum (look out for *Android Development*). There should be tutorials on how to install ROMs, recoveries, kernels etc., too.